# Camera2 API: picture is taken 4-5 seconds after the request was submitted

Tags: android, android-camera2

The goal is simple: just make a picture using **front** camera. Picture should be fixed at the moment of photo request sending. Preview is not even needed, so the `CameraSession` is instantiated using the single surface, which comes from `ImageReader`. But the problem is that on some devices the picture is **captured** only 4-5 seconds after. Here are some logs:

> Photo was requested at 13:47:29.049
>
> Capture was requested on 13:47:29.062
>
> File was written, sending file to the channel on 13:47:33.313
>
> Photo file was received at 13:47:33.339
>
> Photo was requested at 13:47:39.073
>
> Capture was requested on 13:47:39.074
>
> File was written, sending file to the channel on 13:47:43.199
>
> Photo file was received at 13:47:43.215

The issue is that the picture is **captured** 4 seconds after and the **autofocus** feature is not supported (tested on Xiaomi MI-5). How to eliminate either such a long delay before **capturing** or perform focus locking? Or may be here is an another solution to eliminate the stated problem?

Worth mentioning ASUS's tablet logs:

> Photo was requested at 07:07:03.443
>
> Capture was requested on 07:07:03.454
>
> File was written, sending file to the channel on 07:07:03.907
>
> Photo file was received at 07:07:03.944
>
> Photo was requested at 07:07:08.449
>
> Capture was requested on 07:07:08.449
>
> File was written, sending file to the channel on 07:07:08.635
>
> Photo file was received at 07:07:08.651

Here is the code:

ViewModel:

```
private fun makePhoto() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Main) {
        Log.i("Photo", "Photo was requested at ${LocalTime.now()}")
        val picture: File = camera.makePhoto()
        Log.i("Photo", "Photo file was received at ${LocalTime.now()}")
        //process the file somehow
    }
}
```

PhotoCamera:

```
//the method is called in onStart of an Activity or Fragment instance
override suspend fun open() {
    val surfaces = listOf(outputSurface) //surface of an ImageReader instance, comes into object's constructor
    cameraDevice =
        suspendCoroutine { cameraManager.openCamera(specification.id, SuspendingCameraStateCallback(it), handler) } //callback just resumes the coroutine with CameraDevice when onOpened method was called.
    session = suspendCoroutine { cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, SuspendSessionCallback(it), handler) } //same, just resumes the continuation with the session that comes into onConfigured method
}

override suspend fun makePhoto(): File {
    return suspendCoroutine {
        session.apply {
            stopRepeating()
            abortCaptures()
            Log.i("Photo", "Capture was requested on ${LocalTime.now()}")
            capture(createCaptureRequest(outputSurface), captureAwaitFactory.createListener(it), handler)
        }
    }
}

private fun createCaptureRequest(target: Surface): CaptureRequest {
    val requestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
    requestBuilder.addTarget(target)
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, orientation.rotation)
    return requestBuilder.build()
}
```

ImageReader listener's code that is attached using setOnImageAvailableListener:

```
override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
    reader.acquireLatestImage().use { image: Image ->
        val byteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
        val byteArray = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
        byteBuffer.get(byteArray)
        val outputFile = createOutputFile()
        FileOutputStream(outputFile).use { stream: FileOutputStream -> stream.write(byteArray) }
        Log.i("Photo", "File was written, sending file to the channel on ${LocalTime.now()}")
        scope.launch {
            fileChannel.send(outputFile)
        }
    }
}

private fun createOutputFile() = //creates a unique file
```

Factory's `createListener` implementation:

```
override fun createListener(continuation: Continuation<File>): CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback {
    return CoroutineCaptureCallback(channel, this, continuation)
}
```

And `CoroutineCaptureCallback`'s code:

```
internal class CoroutineCaptureCallback(
    private val channel: ReceiveChannel<File>,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val continuation: Continuation<File>
) : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    override fun onCaptureCompleted(
        session: CameraCaptureSession,
        request: CaptureRequest,
        result: TotalCaptureResult
    ) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
        scope.launch {
            continuation.resume(channel.receive())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that runs when the capture session has been created is not included, so it's hard to tell what you do at that point.

That said, you should likely be issuing a repeating capture request in order to converge autoexposure and autofocus, otherwise your image capture may use very bad values for those.  For that, I'd recommend adding a second Surface target, like a dummy SurfaceTexture (created with some random texture ID as argument; just never call updateTexImage on it and you don't need GL context or anything).

That way, once you issue your photo capture request, everything is ready and spun up.